# Resetting the .style of an element / reverting to 'initial' without .style overriding

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I have a div (`.projectTitle`) inside of another div (`.projectContainer`). When the screen is greater than 1000px wide, `.projectTitle` is initialized with `opacity:0;`. When the screen is less than 1000px wide, it is initialized with `opacity:1;`. See:

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .projectTitle {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .projectTitle {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

Now, if `.projectContainer` is hovered over while the screen is wider than 1000px, the opacity of `.projectTitle` should animate to 1, and back to 0 when unhovered. However, nothing should happen if it is hovered over when the screen is LESS than 1000px; it should alway remain at 1 in this case.

I have a variable (`windowState`) that changes depending on the width of the screen:

less than 1000px, windowState = 3

greater than 1000px, windowState = 2

I have a jQuery event that looks like this to handle the hovering, which does it's job properly:

```
$(".projectContainerr").hover(
    function(){
        if (windowState != 3){
            $('.projectTitle', this).animate({
                opacity:1},100);
        }
    },
    function(){
        if(windowState != 3){
            $('.projectTitle', this).animate({
                opacity:"initial"},100);
        }
    }
);
```

## The Problem

When opacity is reset to it's value of `initial` (aka, the value as defined in the media queries) after unhovering, that value is overridden by the fact that it was already set to 1, when hovered onto. The "1" value from hovering is placed into the element's style, overriding the inherited value from the css that 'initial' has returned it to.

How do I prevent this value from overriding / reset it / animate without using the element's style?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you handle your fade in via css3? i.e. Remove your javascript and in your first media query add `.projectTitle:hover{ transistion: all .3ms; opacity: 1; }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do it using css3 transition instead of jQuery

```
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .projectContainer:hover .projectTitle{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  }
  .projectTitle {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .projectTitle {
    opacity:1;

  }
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/ruciqe/1/edit?output)

Comment: And you can avoid using jquery

Comment: Keeping presentation where it belongs ;) ty css3!

Comment: Hey, this is great! I considered CSS transitions, but I didn't know much about them, so I had no idea that you could link the hovering of one element with the transition of another! One question: how do I get it to transition the opacity back to 0 when unhovering? There doesn't seem to be an `:unhover` selector. EDIT: Scratch that, the transition properties should be in the .projectTitle style, not the hover style! Working now!